# Como puedo convertir una sentencia SQL a Eloquent builder de laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

Intente pero no me da el resultado como tal:

sentencia sql:

```
SELECT groups.name, users.role_id, users.firstname
FROM groups
INNER JOIN group_user 
        ON groups.id = group_user.group_id
INNER JOIN users 
    ON group_user.user_id = users.id 
    WHERE users.role_id = 3 AND group_user.user_id = 6
```

intentando con el builder de laravel:

```
    ->join('group_user', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->join('users', 'group_user.user_id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->where('users.role_id', '=', '3')
    ->select('groups.name','users.firstname')
    ->get();

return $group_select;
```

Ejecutando la sentencia del builder anterior si me arroja resultados pero falta 1 where y aun si pongo el where no me aparecen los resultados

Comment: Muestranos como colocas el segundo where

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo el problema esta en el join de users, especificamente en esta linea:

```
->join('users', 'group_user.user_id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
```

Pero deberia quedar de la siguiente manera ya que tienes que hacer referencia a users.user_id con group_user.user_id, asi deberia quedar tu codigo  :

```
->join('users', 'users.user_id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
```

Espero que te ayude.